# Dispatch used in UseEffect hook not changing immediately the state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this code, where I'm drawing some Google Maps markers. I have a form where I put the ID for a certain order and the marker for that order should disappear, but it's gone only after refreshing the page. I got in this situation a couple times and got stuck with finding a solution. The problem is in the useEffect hook, cause the hook is triggered but the list of orders doesn't update on time.

```
const [confirmOrder, setConfirmOrder] = useState(0);
const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState('');

const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {

    dispatch(listOrders());

}, [dispatch, confirmOrder]);

<LoadScript libraries={libs} googleMapsApiKey={googleApiKey}>
                <GoogleMap id="sample-map" mapContainerStyle={{ height: '80%', width: '100%' }}
                    center={center}
                    zoom={15}
                    onLoad={onLoad}
                    onIdle={onIdle}>
                    {loading ? (<LoadingBox></LoadingBox>)
                        :
                        error ? (<MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>)
                            :
                            (<div>
                                {
                                    orders.map((order) => ( order.isDelivered === false ? (<Marker key={order.shippingAddress.lat} position={{ lat: order.shippingAddress.lat, lng: order.shippingAddress.lng }}></Marker>):undefined))
                                    
                                }
                            </div>)
                    }
                </GoogleMap>
            </LoadScript>
...
<form className='form-map'>
                <div className='formfield'>
                    <label htmlFor='orderId' className='label'>Confirm Order</label>
                    <input type="text" id="orderId" placeholder='ID Order' required className='input' onChange={e=>setOrderId(e.target.value)}></input>
                </div>
                <button type="button" className='map-button' onClick={() => confirmOrderHandler(orderId)}>Confirm order delivery </button>
            </form>
```

Thia is my action:

```
export const deliverOrder = (orderId) => async(dispatch, getState) => {
dispatch({ type: ORDER_DELIVER_REQUEST, payload: orderId });
const { userSignin: { userInfo } } = getState();
try {
    const { data } = Axios.put(`/api/orders/${orderId}/deliver`, {}, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
    });
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_DELIVER_SUCCESS, payload: data });
} catch (error) {
    const message = error.response && error.response.data.message ?
        error.response.data.message : error.message;
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_DELIVER_FAIL, payload: message });
}
```

};

This is my reducer:

```
export const orderDeliverReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case ORDER_DELIVER_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true };
    case ORDER_DELIVER_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, success: true };
    case ORDER_DELIVER_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case ORDER_DELIVER_RESET:
        return {};
    default:
        return state;
}
```

};

And this is my store:

```
const initialState = {
userSignin: {
    userInfo: localStorage.getItem('userInfo') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo')) : null
},
cart: {
    cartItems: localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) : [],
    shippingAddress: localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress')) : {},
    paymentMethod: 'PayPal',
}
};

const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
    userSignin: userSigninReducer,
    userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
    orderCreate: orderCreateReducer,
    orderDetails: orderDetailsReducer,
    orderPay: orderPayReducer,
    orderMineList: orderMineListReducer,
    userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
    userUpdateProfile: userUpdateProfileReducer,
    productCreate: productCreateReducer,
    productUpdate: productUpdateReducer,
    productDelete: productDeleteReducer,
    orderList: orderListReducer,
    orderDelete: orderDeleteReducer,
    orderDeliver: orderDeliverReducer,
    userList: userListReducer,
    userDelete: userDeleteReducer,
    userUpdate: userUpdateReducer,
    productCategoryList: productCategoryListReducer,
    productReviewCreate: productReviewCreateReducer,
    userAddressMap: userAddressMapReducer,
});
```

Comment: Can you share your store/reducer logic?
THere doesn't seem anything wrong with current code

Comment: done, also I put the dispatch in an async function and seems to work..
`useEffect(() => {
        const updateMarkers = async () =>{
            dispatch(listOrders());
        }
        updateMarkers();
    }, [dispatch, confirmOrder]);`